# ReflectionException: Class Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate does not exist in file

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to get user details with token (in postman). But I'm getting error:

```
ReflectionException: Class Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate does not exist in file C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 779
```

[image]

My app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware= [
    ...
    'auth.jwt' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ...
];
```

My config\app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
    ...
 ],
```

My project github: https://github.com/vika0/project

Comment: hi vika, comment the line where have imported the jwauth(app.php and kernel) and then do composer require tymon/jwt-auth. I put here a tutorial to install these plugins into laravel(https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/)

Comment: I did those steps, and now I'm getting eror: `ReflectionException: Class auth.jwt does not exist in file`

Comment: do composer install with the dependencies commented( like my first comment)

Comment: I did `composer require tymon/jwt-auth`. Now I did it again and got:`Nothing to install or update  `

Comment: ok, lets see we do this more easy put your composer.json of the proyect in the answer, then i thought why your proyect dont work with your code

Comment: https://github.com/vika0/project/blob/master/composer.json
This is my composer.json file up to date

Comment: remove of kernel the line of the plugin, you dont need that line 'auth.jwt' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class

Comment: can i get your proyect and test in my computer? if i can do it without error, also you can

Comment: I was ted that line in my localhsot project. Now all files in github are also updated, sorry for that.
So, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register` pages are working, but I'm still getting `ReflectionException: Class auth.jwt does not exist in file`, when i'm connecting to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user?token="TOKEN HERE"`

Comment: vika, can i get your code of github? i dont push any of code only is for see the problem in my computer, there are some things that cause problems in laravel, but without test with the code i cannot see the real problem

Comment: Yes, off course :)

Comment: ok i do it... see in my answer

Comment: what was wrong?

Comment: sorry many things to do for the error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i modify another files that i put after:

You need do it because this error is fixed in develop branch but yet not in master branch, so change something of the plugin.

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

app/Http/Kernel.php(replace of that you have there)

```
    'auth.jwt' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
```

config/jwt.php

```
  'jwt' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to authenticate users.
    |
    */

    'auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Storage Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to store tokens in the blacklist
    |
    */

    'storage' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate',
```

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        //Remove both lines because for me worked without them
        //Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    ],
```

Inside of storage/framework, you need create various folders that are storage/framework/**sessions** and storage/framework/**views**

After of all need do it this command:

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

**[Edited]**

I saw now this screen:

I wish that is that so you want

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183965/discussion-on-answer-by-dherediat-reflectionexception-class-tymon-jwtauth-http).